Colour Ramp Handles adjusting curve radius of "curve to mesh" work on a Spiral but not a Bezier Segment
Why do the colour Ramp Handles adjusting curve radius of "curve to mesh" work on a Spiral but not a Bezier Segment?
When selecting the Bezier Segment the shape is like this and the color ramp handle positions make no difference at all:

When selecting the Spiral the shape is like this and the color ramp handles give full control of the spiral's radius:

Thanks, really confusing me this !

For a Bézier Segment, there are only two control points, one at Factor=0, the other at Factor=1. So only the min/max of the Color Ramp are used. This is why "the color ramp handle positions make no difference at all". Whereas for the Spiral, there are Resolution * Rotations + 1 control points. These information are displayed in the Spreadsheet Editor.

Thanks, that is it, silly mistake ! The Bezier segment has 2 points, one spline and the spiral has 65 points, one spline. Adding a resample curve to the Bezier segment adds those points then permits the adjustment that I was looking for using a Color Ramp or also a Float Curve.

The Bezier segment has 2 points, one spline and the spiral has 65 points, one spline. Adding a resample curve to the Bezier segment adds additional points then permits the adjustment that I was looking for using a Color Ramp or also a Float Curve.
Thanks to StefLAncien
